# Drupal render() - make printed content ucfirst

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-render

I have a drupal template that renders some content like this:

```
<?php $field_collection_state_info = reset($content['field_state_information']['0']['entity']['field_collection_item']);  ?>  
<?php print render($field_collection_state_info['field_state_name']); ?>
```

but I would like to run the php `ucfirst()` so all rendered content is capitalized on the first letter.

I tried this:

```
<?php print ucfirst(render($field_collection_state_info['field_state_name'])); ?>
```

But that didn't work.

How should I achieve this?

Any advise is very much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to change the content of your render array before calling `render()`:

```
// the 'und' part is depending on the translation of the node
$field_collection_state_info['field_state_name']['und'][0]['value'] =
ucfirst($field_collection_state_info['field_state_name']['und'][0]['value']);
// render
print render($field_collection_state_info['field_state_name']);

// or you could try to modify the safe_value part of the array depending on your
// filter settings for the field
$field_collection_state_info['field_state_name']['und'][0]['safe_value'] =
ucfirst($field_collection_state_info['field_state_name']['und'][0]['safe_value']);
// render
print render($field_collection_state_info['field_state_name']);
```

*EDIT* Try adding this into your `template.php`, it changes the value for a collection_field using `hook_preprocess_node()`:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if($vars['type'] == 'YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE') {    
     // you might need to replace the field_content_block with the name of your field <field_state_information>
     $data = reset($vars['content']['field_content_block'][0]['entity']['field_collection_item']);
     // turn the first character to uppercase
     $data['field_text']['#object']->field_text['und'][0]['value'] = ucwords($data['field_text']['#object']->field_text['und'][0]['value']);
    // set the data in the array, like I said above your might need to change the `field_collection_block` to `field_state_information`
    $vars['content']['field_content_block'][0]['entity']['field_collection_item'] = $data;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Krister. I'm getting this error: `Notice: Undefined index: und in include() ` Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Krister ... I added a line from my code above that may help with why this is not working. Sorry I didn;t post it before.

Comment: @cybercampbell - What is the name of your template file?

Comment: @cybercampbell - I made an update to my answer, that uses `hook_preprocess_node()` instead. I tried it on my own installation on a content type that has a field_collection containing an image and a text field.

Comment: Thanks @Krister ... what do I put for `YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE` as this is profile2 data displyed with a view.

Comment: @cybercampbell - The type of node that holds the field you wan't to change. If your view contains nodes of type `Country` and that content type has a field called `field_state_information` then your would change it to `country`.

Comment: In the above example you would also need to replace the `field_text` part with the name of your actual field, in your case `field_state_name`.

Comment: If you could export your view and send the output to my email I could give you a working example=)

Comment: Did that but can't see any email address.